# Kafka Consumer not reading messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I have Kafka v1.0.1 running on the single node and I am able to push the messages to the topic but somehow unable to consume the message from another node using the below python code.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'kotak-test',
    bootstrap_servers=['kmblhdpedge:9092'],
    auto offset reset='earliest',
    enable auto commit=True,
    group id=' test1',
    value_deserializer-lambda x: loads (x.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    print (message)
```

I am constantly pushing the messages from the console using the below command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer --zookeeper <zookeeper-node>:<port> --topic <topic_name>
```

and also I can read via console

Comment: Did you try changing the group ID?

Comment: please show producer configurations also. And also see the default group-id which kafka uses.
Just checking is 'kmblhdpedge'' resolved ?.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old Zookeeper based producer, but the newer Kafka based Consumer. The logic for how these work and store offsets are not the same.

You need to use `--broker-list` on the Console Producer

Similarly with Console Consumer, use `--bootstrap-server`, not `--zookeeper`

---

Also, these properties should not have spaces in them

```
auto offset reset='earliest',
enable auto commit=True,
group id=' test1',
```